# Tornado cancel httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient fetch() from on_chunk()

Tags: async-await, tornado, coroutine

Inside one of the handlers I am doing the following:

```
    async def get(self):
          client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
          url = 'some url here'
          request = httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=url, streaming_callback=self.on_chunk, request_timeout=120)
          result = await client.fetch(request)
          self.write("done")


    @gen.coroutine
    def on_chunk(self, chunk):
          self.write(chunk)
          yield self.flush()
```

The requests can sometimes be quite large and the client may leave while the request is still in progress of being fetched and pumped to the client. If this happens an exception will appear in the on_chunk function when self.write() is attempted. My question is how do I abort the remaining download if my client went away ?

Comment: Try [HTTPClient.close() method](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient.close).

Comment: Tried to launch a task that will close the client before getting to complete it's download but it will not stop the download. Currently I am working with aiohttp which allows me to stream from the response and work with it in small chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your streaming_callback raises an exception, the client request should be aborted. This will spam the logs with stack traces, but there's not currently a cleaner way to do it. You can override `on_connection_close` to detect when the client has disconnected and set an attribute on `self` that you can check in `on_chunk`.